# Least squares function with 5 unknown parameters

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, optimization, curve-fitting

I am having a trouble with estimation of 5 unknown parameters a, b, c, d, e that are definitely lay in the intervals. It's simply looks this way:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

diap_a = np.arange(0.01, 1, 0.2)
diap_b = np.arange(0.01, 30, 5)
diap_c = np.arange(0.01, 2, 0.5)
diap_d = np.arange(0.01, 2, 0.5)
diap_e = np.arange(0.01, 0.3, 0.03)
X = np.arange(0.01, 1, 0.01) 

def func(a, b, c, d, e):
   return a + b + c + d + e #for example
Y = func(a, b, c, d, e)
```

I have data (expected values) such that

```
Y1 = [60, 59, 58, 57, 56, 55, 50, 30, 10]
X1 = [0.048, 0.049, 0.05, 0.05, 0.06, 0.089, 0.1, 0.12, 0.134]
```

I was trying to implement it this way:

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, a, b, c, d, e, Y1, X1)
```

to find optimal a, b, c, d, e that will help to fit the curve

```
plt.plot(Y, X)
plt.show()
```

But it doesn't work.

The result is:

```
OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated
```

Sorry for my bad formulation of the problem.

Comment: That's not how `curve_fit` is used. Have you read the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html)?

Comment: Yes, I was trying to implement using the example from documentation, but did not understand how to include these 5 parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your curve_fit() should take func, X1, and Y1 as the first three parameters according to the curve_fit() documentation. As currently coded, func() will always return a single value that has nothing to do with X1 and cannot fit the data. Here is an example graphing fitter using your data that has three parameters and uses scipy's default initial parameter estimates of all 1.0 - these are not always optimal. If you get a bad fit of the data to any given function it might be the initial parameter estimates, and so scipy has a genetic algorithm module to help find those estimates if needed.

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

xData = numpy.array([0.048, 0.049, 0.05, 0.05, 0.06, 0.089, 0.1, 0.12, 0.134])
yData = numpy.array([60, 59, 58, 57, 56, 55, 50, 30, 10])


def func(x, a, b, c): # simple quadratic example
    return (a * numpy.square(x)) + b * x + c


# these are the same as the scipy defaults
initialParameters = numpy.array([1.0, 1.0, 1.0])

# curve fit the test data
fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, initialParameters)

modelPredictions = func(xData, *fittedParameters) 

absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))

print('Parameters:', fittedParameters)
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = func(xModel, *fittedParameters)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```